# How to edit and update data in local storage?

Tags: javascript

I've been researching for hours and asked a number of times in stack overflow, but the answers did not help or I don't understand at all (user made use of jquery and php as part of solution which I do not know how to use)

Here are my codes (currentuser-will only show when user is logged in)

```
var currentUser=userList;
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",loadUserData);

function loadUserData() {
currentUser = localStorage.getItem("currentUser");
if(currentUser!=null) {
currentUser = JSON.parse(currentUser);

document.getElementById('username').value = currentUser.username;
document.getElementById('name').value = currentUser.name;
document.getElementById('password').value = currentUser.password;
document.getElementById('email').value = currentUser.email; 




console.log(currentUser.username);
console.log(currentUser.name);
console.log(currentUser.password);
console.log(currentUser.email);
    }
}
```

My codes to add users as objects into an array when they sign up for an account:

```
var userList;

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", loadUserList);

function loadUserList(){
    if(localStorage.getItem("userList")===null) {
         userList = [] ;
    } else {
         userList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userList'));
    }

}
function saveUserToStorage(){


var u=document.getElementById("username").value;
var n=document.getElementById("name").value;
var p=document.getElementById("password").value;
var e=document.getElementById("email").value;

var user={"username":u,"name":n,"password":p,"email":e};
localStorage["user"]=JSON.stringify(user);
userList.push(user);
localStorage.setItem('userList',JSON.stringify(userList));

}
```

When I log in, it would direct me to the edit profile page and display data in the form which the user had entered when signing up. 
What I NEED right now is just to change the local storage data by filling in the form. Just like editing it through the Inspect Element, just that it's being edited through the edit profile form. How do i achieve this?

Please help me. Would appreciate solutions without jquery/php

Sample of local storage:

Before editing

```
{"username":"alice66","name":"alice tan","password":"123","email":"abc@mail.com"}
```

After editing (through edit profile page)

```
{"username":"ben66","name":"ben ong","password":"qwerty","email":"xyz@mail.com"}
```

What would be the correct function to do so?

I tried the following function but it did not work:

```
var updatedUser=currentUser;
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",saveChanges);
function saveChanges() {
updatedUser = localStorage.getItem("updatedUser");
updatedUser = JSON.parse(updatedUser);
var u = document.getElementById("username").value = updatedUser.username;
var n = document.getElementById("name").value = updatedUser.name;
var p1 = document.getElementById("password1").value = updatedUSer.password1;
var p2 = document.getElementById("password2").value = updatedUser.password2;
var e = document.getElementById("email").value = updatedUser.email;

updatedUser={"username":u,"name":n,"password1":p1,"password2":p2,"email":e};
updatedUser.push(updatedUser);
localStorage.setItem('updatedUser',JSON.stringify(updatedUser));
}
```

Comment: Look into the browsers console. It will throw understandable errors

Comment: so.. you are saving users in their own browser cache?

Comment: @Jonasw thanks for ur help, no it didn't show any errors

Comment: @user2267175 yeah, sth like that . I just need help in updating through the form instead of manually editing in the Inspect Element

Comment: i would make a bunch of console.logs thoughout your problem code and check it in chrome to see if some variables are undefined or it suddenly stops executing somewhere(e.g. if you make 10 console.logs but only 6 are actually executed & viewable in the console, something is mostlikely happening between the 6'th and 7'th which is breaking the code.

Comment: Please edit your question so that it only contains the code necessary to understand your problem.

Comment: @Mike the above two codes r just for reference purposes, in case the codes needed to write the function requires the naming of the codes from above. I tried the last code below but it didn't work. mind helping?

Answer (score 1):

It is rather simple

https://jsfiddle.net/ft3ur0cw/5/

```
<input placeholder="name" id="name"><br/>
<input placeholder="nausernameme" id="username"><br/>
<input placeholder="password" id="password"><br/>
<input placeholder="email" id="email"><br/><br/>
<button id="save" >save</button>
<br/><br/>
<input placeholder="name_saved" id="name_saved"><br/>
<input placeholder="nausernameme_saved" id="username_saved"><br/>
<input placeholder="password_saved" id="password_saved"><br/>
<input placeholder="email_saved" id="email_saved"><br/><br/>


function load_user(){
    var userdata = localStorage.getItem("userdata");
  if(typeof userdata === undefined || userdata === null){
    userdata = JSON.stringify({username:"",name:"",password:"",email:""});
    localStorage.setItem("userdata",userdata);
  }
    return JSON.parse(userdata);
}

function save_user(username , name, password, email){
    userdata = JSON.stringify({username:username,name:name,password:password,email:email});
    localStorage.setItem("userdata",userdata);
      return userdata;
}

document.getElementById('save').addEventListener("click",function(){
    save_user(
    document.getElementById('username').value,
    document.getElementById('name').value,
    document.getElementById('password').value,
    document.getElementById('email').value
    );
  userdata = load_user();
    document.getElementById('username_saved').value = userdata.username;
    document.getElementById('name_saved').value = userdata.name;
    document.getElementById('password_saved').value = userdata.password;
    document.getElementById('email_saved').value = userdata.email;
});

userdata = load_user();
    document.getElementById('username_saved').value = userdata.username;
    document.getElementById('name_saved').value = userdata.name;
    document.getElementById('password_saved').value = userdata.password;
    document.getElementById('email_saved').value = userdata.email;
```

this is pretty much how it goes.

EDIT:
better example demonstrating the use of the functions

Comment: the save_user function might run into problems, 
if i set the name to foobar, i can imagine it would be saved as "foobar:foobar" instead of "name:foobar"

Comment: no not really. Though maybe not good as an example, but 
{name:name} in javascript signifies an object, with a property called name, wich will be initiated with the value of a variable named name.
As an example try to execute this || var name = "a"; console.log({name:name});

Comment: I tried your codes with bit of modification, the local storage data doesn't get updated.

Comment: please try to fork the jsfiddle code up to the point it does not work, so that i may help you

Comment: actually what does the save_user function do? i can't really see the error in jsfiddle, since I would depend on the inspect element to check if the userdata in local storage is changed. https://jsfiddle.net/ft3ur0cw/1/

Comment: i updated my example to betterdemostrate its use, take a look at it again

Comment: Thanks so much, that's exactly how I want the local data to be updated, I'll try to integrate it into my current codes, thanks:)