# Userdata doesn't get updated in local storage

Tags: javascript

My  HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<title>Edit Profile</title>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="EditProfileCSS.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="EditProfileJS.js"/></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="CommonScript.js"/></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CommonStyle.css"/>

<script>
var currentUser=userList;

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",loadUserData);

function loadUserData() {
currentUser = localStorage.getItem("currentUser");
if(currentUser!=null) {
currentUser = JSON.parse(currentUser);

document.getElementById('username').value = currentUser.username;
document.getElementById('name').value = currentUser.name;
document.getElementById('password').value = currentUser.password;
document.getElementById('email').value = currentUser.email; 




console.log(currentUser.username);
console.log(currentUser.name);
console.log(currentUser.password);
console.log(currentUser.email);
    }
}


function saveChanges(username , name, password, email){
currentUser = JSON.stringify({username:username,name:name,password:password,email:email});
localStorage.setItem("currentUser",currentUser);
  return currentUser;
}

document.getElementById('saveChanges').addEventListener("click",function(){
saveChanges(
document.getElementById('username').value,
document.getElementById('name').value,
document.getElementById('password').value,
document.getElementById('email').value
);
 currentUser = loadUserData();
document.getElementById('username').value = currentUser.username;
document.getElementById('name').value = currentUser.name;
document.getElementById('password').value = currentUser.password;
document.getElementById('email').value = currentUser.email;
});


</script>

</head>
<body onload="loadUserData()">
<!--edit profile-->
<form action="EditProfile.html" method="post" id="userData" onload="loadUserData()">
<h2 id="title">Edit Profile</h2>
<fieldset id="fieldset">
<div class="content">
<p>
<label for="profilepic">Change Profile Picture<!--img    src="images/profile_pic.png"/--></label>

<input type="file" id="profilepic" name="profilepic" accept="image/*"   onchange="uploadPicture(event)" />
<img id="output"/>
</p>
<p>
<label for="newusername">Username:</label>
<input type="text" name="username"  id="username"  required="required"/>
</p>
<p>
<label for="name">Name:</label>
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" required="required"/>
</p>
<p>
<label for="cpassword">Current Password:</label>
<input type="password" id="password" name="password"  required="required"/> 
</p>

<p>
<label for="password1">New Password:</label>
<input type="password" id="password1" name="password1" />
</p>
<p>
<label for="password2">Confirm Password:</label>
<input type="password" id="password2" name="password2"  />
</p>

<p>
<label for="email">Change Email:</label>
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" required="required"/>

</p>


</form>

 <input type="submit" id="saveChanges" value="Save Changes" onclick="Validate();"  onclick="VerifyPassword();"/>
</div>
</fieldset>
</body>
</html>
```

What I want is to update info from local storage by editing info through a form. 
From

```
{"username":"hello99","name":"jane","password":"123","email":"g@gmail.com"}
```

To

```
{"username":"hello89","name":"jane lim","password":"pass","email":"h@mail.com"}
```

in local sotrage

Link to previous question: [How to edit and update data in local storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38806425/how-to-edit-and-update-data-in-local-storage)

EDIT: I changed the way I asked my question due to a feedback from another user that I'm asking the wrong way. Hope this satisfied you, I didn't mean it

Comment: I've modified my way of asking hope it satisfies you

Comment: That seems absolutely fine; though I'd still link to the previous question to provide context (it may, or may not, be important or relevant but might give some insight as to how the problem developed and, in some cases, might enable someone to answer your previous question in a better, or alternative, way that may also address this problem). Thank you for taking my criticism so well, and productively! :)

Comment: I've done linking to the previous question:) if u do know javascript mind helping me?

Comment: I'm trying to understand the question, it seems like you want to store the username, name, password and email address in a JSON object in the browser's local storage? Loading those details from local storage into an edit form and then save the amended details back to the local storage? Could you add your HTML to the question as well? Enough that we have a [MCVE] snippet of your code that reproduces your problem?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I wanted to do. I have managed to load the details into the form. I just have trouble trying to edit it back into local storage

Comment: I have copied my html into my question, there's an external javascript linked to it as well, so is it okay if u copy the above html, then i'll replace it with the other script?

Comment: uhm hello r u still there? @DavidThomas

Comment: What do you expect `currentUser = loadUserData();` to do, given that `loadUserData()` doesn't have a `return` statement and thus returns `undefined`?

Comment: I didn't spot any error which returns `undefined`, My error now shows `cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null`

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend the following approach:

```
// making an object comprised of functions,
// in order to group related functions together:
var userData = {
  'get': function() {
    // here we retrieve the stored data (stored with
    // the key of 'data'):
    var data = window.localStorage.getItem('data');

    // typically retrieving an item that doesn't exist
    // will store null as the value of the variable to
    // which that item should be assigned, but here we
    // check for undefined as well (just to be sure):
    if (null === data || 'undefined' === typeof data) {
      // we exit the function here, since there's nothing
      // to be done with an empty/null data variable:
      return false;
    } else {

      // otherwise, if we have data, then we pass that
      // JSON string to JSON.parse() to turn it into
      // an iterable object:
      data = JSON.parse(data);
    }

    // we should have data at this point (since if we
    // we didn't we should have exited the function),
    // but I really like to be sure:
    if (data) {

      // retrieving an Array of keys from the data
      // object, and iterating over that array with
      // Array.prototype.forEach():
      Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) {
        // 'key' : the first argument is a reference
        //         to the current array-element of
        //         the array of keys over which
        //         we're iterating.

        // we retrieve the element from the document with
        // the id matching the key, and assign the
        // defaultValue of that element to the stored
        // value from the data Object:
        document.getElementById(key).defaultValue = data[key];
      })
    }
  },
  'set': function(e) {
    // because we're binding this function to an element
    // using addEventListener the even is passed through
    // automatically, therefore we call event.preventDefault()
    // to prevent the default action of the element,
    // for a button on a form element that default action
    // may cause a page reload, which we don't want:
    e.preventDefault();

    // finding the relevant form fields to be stored:
    var fields = document.querySelectorAll('#username, #name, #email, #password'),
      // converting the HTMLCollection returned from
      // document.querySelectorAll() into an Array,
      // using Array.from() if it's available or,
      // otherwise, an older approach which calls
      // Array.prototype.slice() to convert the
      // HTMLCollection into an Array:
      fieldArray = Array.from ? Array.from(fields) : Array.prototype.slice.call(fields, 0),

      // initialising an Object to store the
      // properties temporarily:
      store = {};

    // if every element in the array of elements has
    // a truthy trimmed value, or defaultValue, with
    // a length > 0 we go ahead:
    if (fieldArray.every(function(el) {
        return (el.value || el.defaultValue).trim().length;
      })) {
      // iterating over the fieldArray:
      fieldArray.forEach(function(input) {

        // if the value of the <input> element,
        // once trimmed (removing leading and
        // trailing white-space) has a length
        // greater than 0 (0 is falsey):
        if (input.value.trim().length) {

          // we set the key of of the value to
          // store to the id of the current
          // <input> element, and store the
          // value in the object with that key:
          store[input.id] = input.value;

          // we also remove the 'error' class-
          // name if the element has that class:
          input.classList.remove('error');
        } else {

          // otherwise, we set the value to that
          // held in the defaultValue:
          input.value = input.defaultValue;

          // add the 'error' class-name:
          input.classList.add('error');

          // and store the defaultValue in the
          // Object, since the Object itself
          // will overwrite the stored Object
          // so we need to explicitly re-store
          // the old value to prevent empty
          // entries:
          store[input.id] = input.defaultValue;
        }
      });

      // here we store the data in localStorage with the
      // key of 'data' and the value as the JSON string
      // formed by the 'store' Object:
      window.localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(store));

      // otherwise, given that we have no pre-existing data to
      // store, we don't store any supplied data and we add an
      // 'error' class-name to each field that doesn't yet
      // hold a value (note that I'm not testing for validity
      // of values, simply existence):
    } else {

      // using Array.prototype.filter() to filter the Array
      // of elements to keep only those whose value, or
      // defaultValue, is 0 once it's trimmed:
      fieldArray.filter(function(el) {
        // removing the 'error' class-name from
        // each element:
        el.classList.remove('error');
        return (el.value || el.defaultValue).trim().length === 0;
      }).forEach(function(el) {
        // adding the 'error' class-name to each of the
        // elements that are retained from the filter:
        el.classList.add('error');
      });
    }

    // purely for debuggging, so that you can see what's
    // being saved; remove this (obviously) once you're
    // happy:
    document.getElementById('result').textContent = window.localStorage.getItem('data');
  },

  // the clear function, to allow the user to
  // empty/remove their stored data:
  'clear': function(e) {
    // again we use event.preventDefault() to
    // prevent the default action:
    e.preventDefault();

    // and then we clear the localStorage:
    window.localStorage.clear();

    // we could, instead, simply use:
    // window.localStorage.removeItem('data');
    // to do the same thing, but this will only
    // remove the 'data' item, and leave anything
    // and everything else; which seems like a
    // bad UI based on user-expectation.

    // clearing the visible data from the <form>
    // with which this <button> element was associated:
    this.form.reset();
  }
}

// binding the named functions (note the lack of parentheses) to
// the named events of the elements:
document.querySelector('#save').addEventListener('click', userData.set);
document.querySelector('#clear').addEventListener('click', userData.clear);

// calling the get() function on page-load:
userData.get();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/6swuf3me/).

This, unfortunately, doesn't seem to be supported in Stack Snippets due to the need to access localStorage which isn't available (so far as I can see) in the Snippet sandbox.

References:

- [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).
- [`Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).
- [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).
- [Conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/conditional_operator).
- [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).
- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
- [`Element.classList` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).
- [`Event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).
- [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).
- [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).
- [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).
- [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).
- [`String.prototype.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim).
- [`typeof` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof).
- [`Window.localStorage` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).